# Pycharm: property cannot be set

Tags: python

I'm trying to override flask_jsonrpc's formatter method:

```
from flask_jsonrpc import exceptions

def override_jsonrpc_error_formatter(app):
    @property
    def json_rpc_format(self):
        return ErrorFormatter.format_error(self)

    exceptions.Error.json_rpc_format = json_rpc_format
```

**override_jsonrpc_error_formatter** function is called in a different file then.

Everything works, but pycharm shows me a warning for the last string, saying: "property json_rpc_format cannot be set". Why is it happening? Do I need to override it in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [setters](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php)

In you case I would do something like:

```
class CustomError(Error):

    @property
    def json_rpc_format(self):
        return self._json_rpc_format

    @json_rpc_format.setter
    def json_rpc_format(self, value):
        self._json_rpc_format = value
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you import the exceptions from the `flask_jsonrpc` package.

In the package, you can find [these lines](https://github.com/cenobites/flask-jsonrpc/blob/master/flask_jsonrpc/exceptions.py#L67):

```
class Error(Exception):
    """Error class based on the JSON-RPC 2.0 specs
    http://groups.google.com/group/json-rpc/web/json-rpc-1-2-proposal
      code    - number
      message - string
      data    - object
      status  - number    from http://groups.google.com/group/json-rpc/web/json-rpc-over-http JSON-RPC over HTTP Errors section
    """

    code = 0
    message = None
    data = None
    status = 200

    def __init__(self, message=None, code=None, data=None):
        """Setup the Exception and overwrite the default message
        """
        super(Error, self).__init__()
        if message is not None:
            self.message = message
        if code is not None:
            self.code = code
        if data is not None:
            self.data = data

    @property
    def json_rpc_format(self):
        """Return the Exception data in a format for JSON-RPC
        """

        error = {
            'name': text_type(self.__class__.__name__),
            'code': self.code,
            'message': '{0}'.format(text_type(self.message)),
            'data': self.data
        }

        if current_app.config['DEBUG']:
            import sys, traceback
            error['stack'] = traceback.format_exc()
            error['executable'] = sys.executable

        return error
```

So basically, you're trying to overwrite a property of the Error class from the `flask_jsonrpc` package, which is not allowed, because it's an unsettable property.

If you instead want to overwrite it, I think you should inherit from it using a different class, and either import that directly or connect it back to the module.

E.g.:

```
class myCustomError(exceptions.Error):
    @property 
    def json_rpc_format(self):
        return do_some_custom_logic_here()
```